# exist-db: exerr:ERROR Variable $request is not bound to an Java object

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I have the following RESTXQ script in my exist-db 2.2 RC1.
I am trying to path an URL parameter 'path' to main function however I receive  the error

ERROR Variable $request is not bound to an Java object.

```
xquery version "3.0";

module namespace services = "http://my/services";

import module namespace transform = "http://exist-db.org/xquery/transform";
declare namespace request="http://exist-db.org/xquery/request";
declare namespace rest = "http://exquery.org/ns/restxq";
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";
declare namespace json="http://www.json.org";    

declare function local:trim($arg as xs:string?) as xs:string {
    replace(replace($arg,'\s+$',''),'^\s+','')
} ;

....

declare
    %private
function services:func() {

    let $path := request:get-parameter('path', '')
    let $doc := doc(path)
    return 
        <item>
            <uri>{ base-uri($doc) }</uri>
....
```

Full Error:

```
Problem accessing /exist/restxq/document-metadata.json. Reason:

    exerr:ERROR Variable $request is not bound to an Java object. [at line 46, column 18, source: /db/scripts/document-metadata.xql]
In function:
    services:func() [26:3:/db/scripts/document-metadata.xql]
    services:home-json() [-1:-1:/db/scripts/document-metadata.xql]
```

Answer (score 4):

The eXist request, response and session modules are not available in RESTXQ as it has it's own mechanisms instead. So you will not be able to use any functions from `declare namespace request="http://exist-db.org/xquery/request";`